# Error in to.period.contributions() from PerformanceAnalytics sandbox

Tags: r, xts, finance, quantmod, performanceanalytics

I've been trying to calculate my portfolio returns and the individual stock contributions. I stumbled along [this post](https://tradeblotter.wordpress.com/2014/09/25/aggregate-portfolio-contributions-through-time/), which appears to be from the guy who help write PerformanceAnalytics.

At the end of the article he posts a [link to r-forge with a sandbox file](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/PerformanceAnalytics/sandbox/to.period.contributions.R?view=markup&root=returnanalytics) for some functions.

So I'm trying to convert my daily returns to the summed monthly returns via the `to.monthly.contributions()` function but I'm running into an xts error!

Here's my code:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(quantmod)

stock.weights <- c(.15, .20, .25, .225, .175)
symbols <- c("GOOG", "AMZN", "BA", "FB", "AAPL")
getSymbols(symbols, src = 'google', from = "2016")
#xts with daily closing of each stock
merged.closing <- merge(GOOG[,4], AMZN[,4], BA[,4], FB[,4], AAPL[,4])
#xts with returns
merged.return <- na.omit(Return.calculate(merged.closing))
# weighted returns rebalanced quartely
portfolio.returns = Return.portfolio(merged.return, weights = stock.weights,
                                     rebalance_on = "quarters", verbose = TRUE)
#to monthly contributions function
to.monthly.contributions(portfolio.returns$contributions)
```

However when I run the last line I get the following error message:

```
Error in inherits(x, "xts") : 
  argument "Contributions" is missing, with no default 
5. inherits(x, "xts") 
4. is.xts(x) 
3. checkData(Contributions) 
2. to.period.contributions(contributions = contributions, period = "months") 
1. to.monthly.contributions(portfolio.returns$contributions)
```

I'm guessing that the error has something to do with the `portfolio.returns$contributions` not being an xts? But I'm not sure how to get around that.

On the side note, if anyone has any better ideas or sources for calculating portfolio returns by months/quarters/years I'm keen to hear, bearing in mind they need to account for weight changes, re-balances and contributions to changes!

Comment: You have Google twice and no Apple in `merged.closing`. Could that be it?

Comment: I can't find `to.monthly.contributions`.  Which package is that from?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the tutorial. I encounter an error defining the dates in the function and I get the same problem as you do.

Comment: I have fixed the GOOG -> AAPL mistake in the merge.xts. @lebelinoz you can find the to.monthly.contributions in the second link which has the source code for the function.

Comment: @kat
I encountered the same error, however I thought that the 'return' was actually a placeholder for the equivalent of 'merged.return' variable I have.

Answer (score 1):

Note that PerformanceAnalytics (and many other packages in that R-Forge repo) have moved to [Brian Peterson's GitHub account](https://github.com/braverock/).  There you will see some changes to [sandbox/to.period.contributions.R](https://github.com/braverock/PerformanceAnalytics/blob/master/sandbox/to.period.contributions.R) about a year ago.  That might be causing you some issue(s).

Another issue is that the object returned by `Return.portfolio()` does not have a `contributions` element.  The element name you want is `contribution` (singular).

After addressing those two issues, your `to.monthly.contributions()` call works.

```
R> to.monthly.contributions(portfolio.returns$contribution)
              GOOG.Close    AMZN.Close     BA.Close      FB.Close    AAPL.Close Portfolio Return
2016-01-29  0.0002244419 -0.0156956938 -0.036245552  0.0219893367 -1.330565e-02     -0.043033115
2016-02-29 -0.0095461956 -0.0113127380 -0.003625779 -0.0121676134 -1.128288e-03     -0.037780614
2016-03-31  0.0103601952  0.0140210157  0.016927654  0.0171632715  2.218899e-02      0.080661130
2016-04-29 -0.0104584200  0.0222188532  0.015479754  0.0068624014 -2.448619e-02      0.009616397
2016-05-31  0.0085179936  0.0210895602 -0.016873347  0.0024024015  9.732993e-03      0.024869602
2016-06-30 -0.0084883795 -0.0023345382  0.007080427 -0.0086331655 -6.610526e-03     -0.018986182
2016-07-29  0.0166211530  0.0120706520  0.007295757  0.0190190760  1.576098e-02      0.070767622
2016-08-31 -0.0003521895  0.0027014233 -0.007568643  0.0040084230  3.231073e-03      0.002020086
2016-09-30  0.0020684771  0.0177517727  0.004108611  0.0039452914  1.185750e-02      0.039731657
2016-10-31  0.0013990917 -0.0113434690  0.020286170  0.0047711858  7.585139e-04      0.015871492
2016-11-30 -0.0050340240 -0.0092287866  0.015187074 -0.0217047070 -4.601884e-03     -0.025382327
2016-12-30  0.0026858660 -0.0001688763  0.009813394 -0.0059705490  8.286484e-03      0.014646319
2017-01-31  0.0048528154  0.0196327363  0.012429342  0.0298631030  8.355638e-03      0.075133635
2017-02-28  0.0047757941  0.0053484794  0.025108019  0.0094951963  2.198006e-02      0.066707545
2017-03-31  0.0010760715  0.0096512663 -0.004718775  0.0111011780  8.787645e-03      0.025897386
2017-04-28  0.0138145523  0.0086741715  0.011265973  0.0129883844 -1.218154e-05      0.046730900
2017-05-31  0.0101747490  0.0150069699  0.003781232  0.0018310137  1.060194e-02      0.041395909
2017-06-30 -0.0093108126 -0.0055092033  0.013123207 -0.0006974798 -9.767034e-03     -0.012161323
2017-07-31  0.0035934766  0.0040867769  0.056523388  0.0272271162  5.723163e-03      0.097153921
2017-08-31  0.0013284632 -0.0013521084 -0.003226369  0.0036945746  1.691168e-02      0.017356239
2017-09-19 -0.0025908954 -0.0019880088  0.014497492  0.0007343197 -5.737005e-03      0.004915902
```